# Menu doesn't load page when clicked

Tags: nw.js

I'm trying to create a menu, to open various pages with the main window upon starting. This is my js file that is set to be run on package start:

```
var win = null;

function getAppMenu()
{
    var menu = new nw.Menu({type: 'menubar'});
    menu.append(new nw.MenuItem({
        label: 'Home',
        click: function(){
            win.open('index.html');
            alert('asdf');
        }
    }));
    menu.append(new nw.MenuItem({
        label: 'Inventory',
        click: function(){
            alert('asdf');
            win.open('inventory.html', {}, function(win){});
        }
    }));    

    return menu;
}


nw.Window.open('index.html', {id:'main', fullscreen:false, resizable: true, width:800, height:600, focus:true}, function(newwin){
    win = newwin;
    newwin.menu = getAppMenu();
    });
```

The menu is set, but when I click either of the menu items, the page is not loaded. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: pray tell why has this been downvoted, and close voted. who have i pissed off now that their bot attacks me. it's happened on the last 2 questions i've posted now.

Answer (score 0):

`win` is an instance of an nwjs object that does not contain `open` (use `nw.Window.open` instead to open a new window).  If you want to navigate elsewhere, `win.window.location.href = "URL";` is what you're looking for.